# OpenCV(4.1.1) can't find starting number (in the name of file): (camera_stream_Url) in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'

Tags: python, opencv, exe, pyinstaller

My Python script is running required code fine but when I create py to exe and run exe the below error is generated.

```
error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): (camera_stream_Url)  in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'.
```

Comment: It'd be useful if you included the code that is generating the error, plus the input you are supplying to the Python script.

Comment: @beardo thanks for response